# What is wrong with this Obj-C code?

Tags: objective-c

It's an example program in a textbook. It does not run as expected. It's supposed to simulate a sigma calculation and add all the fractions in a series. but it just gives me 0.000000 when it's done the loop. Any ideas? Thanks in advance:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// The Fraction class

@interface Fraction : NSObject

{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void) print;
-(void) set: (int) n: (int) d;
-(double) convertToNum;
-(void) reduce;
-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f;


@end

-------------------------------------

#import "Fraction.h"


@implementation Fraction

@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(void) print

{
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(double) convertToNum
{
    if (denominator != 0) 
        return (int) numerator / denominator;
    else 
        return 1.0;
}

-(void) set:(int)n:(int)d
{
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}


-(void) reduce

{
    int u = numerator;
    int v = denominator;
    int temp;

    while (v != 0) {
        temp = v % u;
        u = v;
        v = temp;
    }

    numerator /= u;
    denominator /= u;
}


-(Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f

{

    Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    int resultNum, resultDenom;

    resultNum = numerator * f.denominator + 
    denominator * f.numerator;
    resultDenom = denominator * f.denominator;

    [result set: resultNum: resultDenom];

    [result reduce];
    return result;
}

@end



--------------------------------------------

#import "Fraction.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init]; 
    Fraction *sum = [[Fraction alloc] init], *sum2; 
    int i, pow2, n;

    // set 1stfraction to 0 

    [sum set: 0.0 : 1.0];



    NSLog (@"Enter your value for n:");
    scanf ("%i", &n);


    pow2 = 2; 
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        [aFraction set: 1 : pow2]; 
        sum2 = [sum add: aFraction]; 
        [sum release]; // release previous sum 
        sum = sum2; 
        pow2 *= 2;


    }

    NSLog (@"After %i iterations, the sum is %f", n, [sum convertToNum]);
    [aFraction release];
    [sum release];




    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `convertToNum` method is declared as returning a double, but the actual value you return is an int (the result of dividing two ints is always an int), so in practice any values less than 1 will be truncated to 0.

Also, as a side note: That coding style, where you don't give names to arguments, is really hard to read. `- (void)set:(int)n :(int)d` is not a good method declaration, and if that's actually used in a book, it should be pulled from print. There's no clue what `n` and `d` are, and the second argument doesn't have *anything* but a colon before it. It should be something like `- (void)setNumerator:(int)aNumerator denominator:(int)aDenominator`.

Comment: +1 to the more readable method signature. One of the great aspects of Objective C in my opinion

Comment: Thank you for your reply; Yes, the text has the set method as "setTo : x over: y", I was just trying it differently. It does mention that its bad practice.  I changed the convertToNum method to return a double, but it's still giving me 0.000000 when the loop is complete. Any further ideas?

-(double) convertToNum
{
 if (denominator != 0) 
  return (double) numerator / (double) denominator;
 else 
  return 1.0;

Answer (score 1):

Your convertToNum function will return 0 when the numerator is smaller than the denominator.  Try changing it to this:

```
-(double) convertToNum
{
    if (denominator != 0) 
        return (double)numerator / (double)denominator;
    else 
       return 1.0;
}
```

Comment: I changed the convertToNum method to return a double, but it's still giving me 0.000000 when the loop is complete. Any further ideas? -(double) convertToNum { if (denominator != 0) return (double) numerator / (double) denominator; else return 1.0;

Comment: @Andrew Jimley check the for loop in main-- when you set sum2 equal to sum and then release sum, you're also releasing sum2, because they're both pointing to the same object.  You also don't have a dealloc method in Fraction... I know enough to know that you should, but not enough to know what will happen here. Try rewriting this loop to copy values from one Fraction to another, instead of releasing and making new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce seems incorrect. I don't know how to make that logic work, but

```
i = 2;
    lLimit = ((lNumerator > lDenominator) ? lNumerator : lDenominator)/2;

while (i < lLimit) {
    if ((lNumerator %  i == 0) &&(lDenominator % i == 0)) {
        lNumerator /= i;
        lDenominator /= i;
        i = 1;
    }
    i++;
}
```

should be closer. sorry for the name changes, but i don't work too well with lots of single letter vars